# Movement in cohorts

Tags: classification, clustering, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance, multilabel-classification

I am working on a user sales data which gets updated week over week. Based on the sales done in each week, the user is categorized in segment A, B or C. This means size of each segment could change week over week.

I am trying to analyze the stability of each segment week over week. However, the caveat is

- We want users to move from "A to B" or "A to C" or "B to C" but we don't want users to move backward from "C to B" or "C to A". So, if size of cohort C grows, it is a good scenario for us

I am looking to assign a score to the entire population based on

- Award +x if user move from A to B or B to C
- Award +y if user move from A to C
- Award +z if a user stays in C
- Penalize -x if user move from B to A or C to B
- Penalize -z if user move from C to A

And then aggregate this for entire population to give a combine score. I have been searching for any algorithm which could help me do this but was not able to find any.

It would be really helpful if you folks from your experience could suggest me any methodology for this.

Thanks in advance!

List item

Answer (score 1):

You have posted an interesting question.
In my opinion, your algorithm would be updated in some ways.

1. Change points for the award and penalty.

Points for the award and penalty are usually different to make users more active on the platform, say, 50 for award and 45  penalty makes users motivated.

2. Award if a user stays in B.

Staying in B could be a bit hard for users. If we award users who stays in B, the possibility of growth of C could be larger.

I am curious if my answers are what you want. If I missed your point, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting thought. Thanks for the input. However, I would need to come up with this number 45 and 50 statistically. Choosing arbitrary number might not be possible for me that's why I was searching for some algorithm that could help me allocate this weights.

Comment: above all, award weight should be greater than the penalty, and y > 2*x, x<z<y.
If you want to adjust weights using Data Science methodology, you can use GAN or Reinforcement Learning algorithms.